# Getting error while making a dropdown menu for discord bot

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, discord.py

Below is the code I am writing The main work is to create a dropdown menu which proceed's with an option to show all the available commands in the bot.

```
#MODULES--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
import os
import time
import json
import discord
from discord.ui import Select, View
from discord.ext import commands

#GETTING DATA FROM CONFIG FILE----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
def load_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)
    
Config_Path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'Config', 'config.json') # File path.

Config_Data = load_data(Config_Path)

# Loading prefix.
Prefix = Config_Data['PREFIX']

#MAIN-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
class HelpMenu(View):
    @discord.ui.select(
        placeholder = "Please choose what you need help with",
        min_values = 1,
        max_values = 1,
        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(label = 'Command Help', description = 'Show info on all the available commands.', emoji = '', value = 1)
        ]
    )
    async def select_callback(self, select, interaction):
        select.disabled = True

        if select.value[0] == '1':
            all_commands = self.bot.commands

            embed = discord.Embed(
                title = 'Bot Commands',
                color = discord.Color.blue()
            )
            for command in all_commands:
                command_name = [f'{Prefix}{command.name}'] + [f'!{alias}' for alias in command.aliases]
                aliases_str = ', '.join(command_name[1:]) if len(command_name) > 1 else 'None'

                embed.add_field(
                    name = command_name[0],
                    value = f'Description: {command.description}\n Aliases: {aliases_str}',
                    inline = False
                )
                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed = embed)

class Commands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    #(1) Custom help command.
    @commands.command(
        name = 'help',
        aliases = ['Help', 'HELP'],
        description = 'Help you to know more about the bot.'
    )
    async def help(self, ctx):
        menu = HelpMenu()
        await ctx.reply(view = menu)

#ADDING THE CLASS TO COG'S--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Commands(bot))
```

The main issue is in the HelpMenu class and in this section

```
async def select_callback(self, select, interaction):
        select.disabled = True
```

This is the error i am geting

```
2024-03-02 18:19:54 ERROR    discord.ui.view Ignoring exception in view <HelpMenu timeout=180.0 children=1> for item <Select placeholder='Please choose what you need help with' min_values=1 max_values=1 disabled=False options=[<SelectOption label='Command Help' value=1 description='Show info on all the available commands.' emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='' id=None> default=False>]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "c:\Users\xesch\OneDrive\Desktop\Spooks\Cogs\commands.py", line 32, in select_callback
    select.disabled = True
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'disabled'
```

I tried finding the solution on chatgpt or youtube but nothing is working.
So I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments in the callback should be the other way around:

```py
async def select_callback(self, interaction, select):
    select.disabled = True
```